# Logic Apps and CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

So I'm trying to do something I expected to be simple - using Logic App to insert a json object into Cosmos DB.

I've created a CosmosDB (based on Core SQL API) and created a container called *Archive* with the partition key /username (which is in my json object).

[image: Creating CosmosDB container]

Now to Logic App.

First, I YOLO'ed the simple approach.
[image: Create or Update CosmosDb V2]

Which gave me error: *"The input content is invalid because the required properties - 'id; ' - are missing"*
But my json object doesnt have an id field. Maybe use the IsUpsert parameter? I dont feel like manipulating my input document to add a field called 'id'.
[image: Upsert parameter added]

Which gave me error: *"One of the specified inputs is invalid"* Okay - feels even worse.

I now tried to use the other logic app connector (Not V2, but the original).
[image: Create or Update CosmosDb]

which gave me error: *"The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer components than defined in the the collection."*

I saw that this connector(unlike the V2 one) has a Partition Key Value parameter from UI, which I added to pass the value of my username [image: with partition key]

which gave me error *"The input content is invalid because the required properties - 'id; ' - are missing"*.

At this point I thought, let me just give the bloody machine what it wants, and so I added "id" to my json object.[image: with "id":"some value" in the json object im trying to insert]
[image: Working Logic App]

and yes that actually worked.
[image: Item inserted]

**So questions are**

1. With Logic Apps connectors, are you only able to insert json objects into Cosmos DB without that magic field "id" in the message payload?
2. If the partitioning key is required. Why is it not available from the V2 connector parameter UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v1 version of this thing doesn't have partition key because it's so old, Cosmos didn't have partitioned containers. You will want to use the v2 preview. I think that will go GA at some point here soon because it's been in preview for a while now.

And yes, With Cosmos DB you can't insert anything without it's id so you will need to generate from whatever calls your endpoint and pass it in the body of your http request.